# Why $("div:visible") can find nothing in jasmine test with phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jasmine, visible

Html code:

```
<div id="xxx"><div>aaa</div></div>
```

Js code:

```
var node = $("#xxx");
var found = node.find("div:visible");
console.log(found.length);
```

If these code are run on browser, it will output `1`. (live demo: http://jsbin.com/xuqule/2/edit)

But when I run it on jasmine test with phantomjs:

```
it("should find the visible nodes", function () {
   var node = $("<div><div>aaa</div></div>");
   var found = node.find("div:visible");
   console.log(found);
   expect(found.length).toEqual(1);
});
```

The test is failed, and the `found.length` is `0`. Why and how to fix it?

Comment: If you don't add the node to the page it isn't visible

Comment: See https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/css/hiddenVisibleSelectors.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not attach anything to the dom, it all lives in memory and that is why you'll get 0.

Try doing something like:

```
$('body').append(node);
var found = node.find("div:visible");
...
```

See bin: http://jsbin.com/kuyagijezono/1/edit

Answer (score 2):

From the docs:

### [:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

> Elements are considered visible **if they consume space in the document**. Visible elements have a width or height that is greater than zero.
>
> Elements with visibility: hidden or opacity: 0 are considered visible, since they still consume space in the layout.
>
> **Elements that are not in a document are considered hidden; jQuery does not have a way to know if they will be visible when appended to a document since it depends on the applicable styles.**

To fix your spec, you need to append the elements to the document, and it should have a `height` and `width`.